# Como consumir o link das imagens através do Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-service

Estou tentando a várias horas consumir os links das imagens de um web service  através do Ajax e não consigo, este é o link do web service (https://api.tenor.com/v1/search?q=happy).

O objetivo é pegar o link da imagem e mostrar a imagem na tela. Diz que esta indefinido o link, não faço a minima ideia porque esta acontecendo isso.

Veja meu código:

```
  $(function(){

    $.ajax({

        url:'https://api.tenor.com/v1/search?q=happy',
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('.gifs').html('<div class="col-md-12"><i class="fas fa-7x fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>');
        },
        success:function(json){

           var html = '';

           for(var i in json){
            html += '<div class="col-md-4"><div class="filme"><img src="'+json[i].weburl+'"/>'+'</div></div>';
           }

           $('.gifs').html(html);
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente fazer desta forma:

```html
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$.ajax({

    url:'https://api.tenor.com/v1/search?q=happy',
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    beforeSend:function(){
        $('.gifs').html('<div class="col-md-12"><i class="fas fa-7x fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>');
    },
    success:function(json){
    var html = '';
    var total = json.results.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < total; i++){
   html += '<div class="col-md-4"><div class="filme"><img src="'+json.results[i].media[0].gif.url+'"/>'+'</div></div>';
       }

       $('.gifs').html(html);
    }

});
});
</script>
<div class="gifs"></div>
```

Comment: Olá. Infelizmente ainda não deu certo. Ao inspecionar elementos consta a url da imagem no código, mas "estranhamente" ainda não apareçe na página.

Comment: Eu editei a resposta, as imagens estão aparecendo

Comment: Agora sim! meu muito obrigado pela ajuda.